# Issue interfacing smart contract with the front end

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm actually trying to write a simple smart contract with front end that takes a value from the user and saves that in the variable in the smart contract.
The index.html part of my project is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   
    <title>Example</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="message"></div>
  <form method="POST">
    <div><input id= "message" name = "message" type= "text">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="register">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>

   
  
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/truffle-contract.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And app.js is

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: '0x0',

  init: function() {
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }
    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON("HelloWorld.json", function(hello) {
      // Instantiate a new truffle contract from the artifact
      App.contracts.HelloWorld = TruffleContract(hello);
      // Connect provider to interact with contract
      App.contracts.HelloWorld.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

      return App.bindEvents();
    });
  },
bindEvents: function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#register', function(){ var msg = $('#message').val(); App.handleMessage(msg);   });
  },

handleMessage: function(msg){

    var hwinstance;
    App.contracts.HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      hwinstance = instance;
      return hwinstance.setMessage(msg);
    }).then( function(result){
      if(result.receipt.status == '0x01')
        alert("successfully")
      else
        alert("failed due to revert")
    }).catch( function(err){
      alert("failed")
    })
  }
  };


  $(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
    console.log('starting app.js');
  });
});
```

The smart contract code that I've written is

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract HelloWorld {
    string private message = "hello world";

    function getMessage() public view returns(string memory) {
        return message;
    }

    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

When I ran the commands truffle complie and truffle migrate, it showed no errors but when I ran 'npm run dev' the page says "Cannot GET /".

I'm not able to understand where the mistake is. Please help!

Is there any other way of interfacing the frontend to the smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

Your local server cannot find your page either because it is in the wrong directory or the local server has not been installed. Run `npm install --save-dev lite-server`. In the package.json you should have something like

```
"script": {
    "dev": "lite-server",
...
}
```

Move your index.html and App.js into `src/` directory you create at the root of the project. Run `npm run dev` to check again. It should work. If you are interested in an easy to use truffle box with react, I have developed a truffle box with React + Material-UI. Take a look here https://github.com/rouftom/truffle-react-material

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell what are some other ways to interact with a smart contract?

Comment: You can use the truffle console which will give you access to your smart contract from the console with the `truffle console` command.

Comment: In the console, you should write something like  
 `YourContract.deployed().then(function(yourContractInstance) { app = yourContractInstance })`. Then you can use `app` variable to interact with your contract.